# Debugging in in emulator with Ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, debugging, cordova, emulation, ionic-framework

I'm very new to Ionic framework and trying to find a way to debug my app. My problem is, I want to check if my Angularjs function call is working in the js file.

As a web developer what I used to do is with Chrome Dev tools by adding some breakpoints and etc..

I'm wondering that is the approach in Ionic framework to check/ debug my Angularjs code? and please note I'm testing a Cordova plugin and it does not support web browser testing.

So is there anyway of adding breakpoints / debug in Ionic apps with emulators (iOS)?

Answer (score 2):

You can connect your device to chrome dev tools and debug your app. It works for Android and iOS. You may also use [GapDebug](https://www.genuitec.com/intro_gapdebug/), which is a free tool encapsulating chrome dev tools.

Comment: GapDebug also wraps Safari's debug tools as well.